# How can I recover files I deleted locally but didn't yet commit?

Tags: git, github

I have this situation:

```
MacBook:Ja.git alan$ git status
On branch alan-1
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/alan-1'.

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/QuizActions.xaml
    deleted:    Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/QuizActions.xaml.cs

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Ja/App/SetResourceColors.cs
    modified:   Ja/App/Styles.cs
    modified:   Ja/Templates/Button/Button.xaml.cs
    modified:   Ja/Views/CardsTab/CardsTab.xaml
    modified:   Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/Actions.xaml
```

Is there a way that I can recover back these files that I just deleted.  Not sure if this helps but the origin still has the latest version of those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by following the prompt message and try:

```
git reset HEAD -- Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/QuizActions.xaml
```

That should unstage the deletion and restore the file with:

```
git checkout -- Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/QuizActions.xaml
```

As commented by torek, this could be done in one step:

```
git checkout HEAD -- Ja/Views/CardsTab/Xaml/Actions/QuizActions.xaml
```

Comment: In this case I'd just use `git checkout HEAD -- <path>`, which does it in one step, but the two-step process is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed anything and you just want to update from remote origin branch you can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

and you will be synced with remote origin

**BEWARE though**: all your local changes will be lost with reset --hard

If you need to save changes do

```
git stash
git pull
```

now check the files are on their place

and apply the stash if you need it

```
git stash pop
```